# Joomla 3.4.3 article intro images not showing

Tags: php, image, joomla, content-management-system

I am using Joomla 3.4.3 and I have an article with the following code..

```
<p>kj<img src="images/demo_preview/about/about1.png" alt="image" width="150" height="150" /></p>
<hr id="system-readmore" />
<p> This is a sample blog posting.</p>
```

I have set article options to show Frontend images but I am only being shown the text.

Here is what i see in the article editor...

[image: Joomla Article Editor View]

and this is what I see on the site...

[image]

as you can see the text only is displayed

Comment: ../images/demo_preview/about/about1.png`?

Comment: That makes no difference on the frontend. In the backend I get the image not found icon. The image url appears to be fine. It's the just the img tag isn't even coming through, just the P tag.

Comment: Can you have a print screen of your view?

Comment: Is this wysiwyg editor?

Comment: Yes, i'm using Tiny MCE

Comment: How do you save your images? And can isee your database?

Comment: I save the images using the media manager in the admin side. What area of the database do you want to see?

Comment: Where you save your images.

Comment: I can't find the part of the database where the images are saved....The file is just uploaded. Or do you mean where the article info is stored?

Comment: I see. Now the problem. Your images must be saved in your database in order for you to retrieve that or the image `src='http://www.image.jpg'`. Try to search your image inside the src if it displays the pic.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Even when I use an external photo it doesn't parse the img tag

Comment: images/demo_preview/about/about1.png type this in the address bar if you see the image

Comment: If you look at the generated source code what link is generated for the image?  (That is go to your browser and view source for that page)  @aldrin27 The images are not saved in the database, this is a joomla question please answer in that context.

Comment: The image is 100% there and nothing regarding the image is brought in. However i did manage to find a solution by changing the _cleanIntroText function in the backend. Will post details later on

Comment: Try using absolute URLs for the images and see if that fixes the problem. I think you have a problem with your base URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a workaround for this problem. It appears that Joomla was stripping out img tags in the article intro text.

I found this function in the helper file...

```
public static function _cleanIntrotext($introtext)
{
    $introtext = str_replace('<p>', ' ', $introtext);
    $introtext = str_replace('</p>', ' ', $introtext);
    $introtext = strip_tags($introtext, '<a><em><strong>');
    $introtext = trim($introtext);

    return $introtext;
}
```

By commenting out the strip_tags function I am able to get img tags back into my articles. It seems like a bit of a hack method to me but it works.

Comment: @jamperz77 Whats the location of this helper file ? i am facing the same issue ? can you please let me know location ?